# Test a React Component with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a component like below, how to conduct the jest testing for the two lines I marked ? Thank you so much

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

       ...
      );
    }
    ...
    render() {
      ...
      if (props && props.context) {                        // need jest testing
        props.context.index = props.context.index || {};   // need jest testing
      }
      
      return <App {...props} />;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Doing side effects in `render` is a mistake, this shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be reassigning prop values at all. What you're doing should be addressed by default props. If you need a component to update a value then you should leverage state.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

App.defaultProps = {
  context: {
    index: {},
  },
};
```

As far as testing those default props, that entirely depends on what exactly you're intending to test. Do you need to assert that the component's state is a certain value in response to those props? Do you need to assert the component's resulting HTML is rendered in a specific way, or that a function results in a specific side effect, etc?